# UIView as UIButton not working (CocoaPod: LGButton)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, cocoapods

I want to use [this cocoa pod](https://github.com/loregr/LGButton) as a button. I picked a UIView, set its class and module to LGButton and edited the design. Then I realized that I just cannot get its feedback. So if you press on the LGButton the Code does NOT recognize the input. My Code:

```
@IBAction func thisLocationPressed(_ sender: LGButton) {
    print("BUTTON PRESSED")
    sender.isLoading = true
    let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(3)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
    sender.isLoading = false
    }
}
```

And YES I linked it to the LGButton in the Main.storyboard. When I press the button, the console NEVER shows "BUTTON PRESSED"... does anyone knows why so?

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Sent Event as "Value Changed" -> Changed to "Touch Up Inside". Works now :)